# How to get Leviathans to stay

Tags: kittens-game

I've had the Leviathans come by a few times and I keep clicking feed elders, and they are always displeased and leave. Is there a certain way to get them to stay? or are the chances of them staying random?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ahh, kittens game. A long time ago...

Anyhow, the faq states that:

> NOTE: You may feed the elders with a sacrifice. If they're pleased, they will stay. If not, they'll just leave.

That will get you nowhere, as you already tried that. So looking into the source code is the next step in unravelling this mystery. It seems to be in the diplomacy tab, and this is the specific code about obtaining Leviathans:

```
var ncorns = this.game.resPool.get("necrocorn");
elders = this.game.diplomacy.get("leviathans");
if (ncorns.value > 0){
    elders.energy += ncorns.value;
    ncorns.value = 0;
    this.game.msg("Elder gods are pleased", "notice");
} else {
    this.game.msg("Elder gods are displeased", "notice");
    elders.duration = 0;
}
```

I haven't played in a long while, so I am unfamiliar with the necrocorns or how to obtain them. In the [faq](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Religion#Marker) it says that you'll get them from the Marker building in the religion tab.

> Effects: Starts a ticking corruption countdown that slowly changes alicorns into **necrocorns**

However, it seems that when you have more then 0 of that (so any), you will get your precious Leviathans.

**TLDR**. Build a Marker building in the religion tab. Obtain Necrocorns. Feed Elders. Obtain Leviathans. Profit.

Comment: oh thank you so much! youve answered my question perfectly! i did not know i needed necrocorns! for not playing in a long time you sure know what your are doing (^: !

Comment: You MUST have necrocorns, but once you do, it's a random function influenced by the number of them you have.

Comment: Necrocorns don't actually do anything. If the Elder Gods accept your sacrifice, they stay for exactly as long as they were going to anyway; if they're displeased, they leave immediately. Either way, your necrocorns are all gone.

Comment: A long time ago? The game is less than 2 years old.

Comment: @codetaku Depending on how many timecrystal you ate ;-)